# How do I draw a mouse in my Cosmos OS?

Tags: c#, operating-system, cosmos

I'm trying to draw a mouse in Cosmos OS but I'm having problems with it.

This is my code:

```
Screen.setPixel(m.X, m.Y, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X + 1, m.Y, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X + 2, m.Y, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X, m.Y + 1, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X, m.Y + 2, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X + 1, m.Y + 1, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X + 2, m.Y + 2, 40);
Screen.setPixel(m.X + 3, m.Y + 3, 40);
```

However, upon running it, I'm getting this error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'Screen' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined your Screen?
If not you may need to define your screen like this:

```
DisplayDriver Screen = new DisplayDriver();
Screen.init();
```

And also you may need to create a new project for the Hardware (that is where you put the display driver code).

If you already have defined it you may need to use it:

```
using Hardware;
```